# Search for tags in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, search

I have a solutions model in my code:

```
public class Solution
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [UIHint("tinymce_full")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tags")]
    public [] string Tag { get; set; }

    public virtual Printer Printer { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id, string searchString, string msg = "")
    {

        var category = await db.Printers.FindAsync(id);

        var c = new ViewModels()
        {
            Printers = db.Printers.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList(),
            Solutions = db.Solutions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList()
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            c = new ViewModels()
            {
                Printers = db.Printers.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList(),
                Solutions = db.Solutions.Where(
                    x => x.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).ToList()
            };

        return View(c);
    }
```

I am adding tags to the db separated by commas in the string array. Instead of the default search which searches for exact strings, I want to be able to search for the solutions via any of the tags in the string array from the database, so that if Solution title is "How to fix a printer jam" I can find it through a tag say "paper stuck in printer".

I am not sure how I can achieve this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad). And remove all those `ToList()` in your queries

Comment: Thanks for that @StephenMuecke but how would I list them in my view if I don't use a `ToList()` ?

Comment: You need to understand what you are doing. Say you have 100K records in your db. Calling `.ToList()` gets them **all** from the database, then you want only a handful of them based on `searchString`. Remove `.ToList()` and you will be using `IQueryable<T>` which means that you will only get just the records you want from the database.

Comment: You are only searching for Title. you have to search for tags as well so you have to modify the query a bit.
Try Change
`Solutions = db.Solutions.Where(
                    x => x.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) | x.Tag.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the advice.. I'm refactoring already.

Comment: @Sam I could do this, but in a situation where the search string doesn't exactly match the the title or tag, maybe it's in reverse order or something, it will return zero results and I don't want that.